# By-step with groovy does not extract values for some node

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, janusgraph, groovy-console

The problem is described as following:

I want to find some interested paths and get corresponding properties of vertices or edges, the groovy I used is as following:

```
g.V().has("p_v_name", "d8e5d39d63c580acdb3eb188a1f4a942").
repeat(__.bothE().otherV().simplePath()).
times(3).emit().
has('p_v_tag').
path().
by(
    __.project("label", "id", "p_v_black_tag").
    by(__.label()).
    by(__.id()).
    by(__.choose(__.has('p_v_tag'),
                __.properties('p_v_tag').project('value').by(__.value()).fold(),
                __.constant([])
                )
    )
).unfold()
```

The above code gives me following result:

```
==>[label:v_user_key,id:749577404608,p_v_tag:[[value:PR016],[value:PR033],[value:PR068]]]
==>[label:e_application_id,id:4jjrk79js-9kcn170g-8ph-nvxhl4s0,p_v_tag:[]]
==>[label:v_application_id,id:1871880949872,p_v_tag:[]]
```

The result is unfolded for easing reading. It's just a path consisted of two nodes and one edge. The source node has a property `p_v_tag`, it's of multi-properties. **The problem is** the target node also has the property `p_v_tag`, but the code does not output the values.

I checked the target node has the property `p_v_tag` and it's not empty as following:

```
gremlin> g.V(1871880949872).properties('p_v_tag')
==>vp[p_v_tag->outdated]
```

I read the document(http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference) over and over but I can't figure out how to make it right, can any body help me or give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why that wouldn't work. What happens if you try this workaround to replace:

```
by(__.choose(__.has('p_v_tag'),
            __.properties('p_v_tag').project('value').by(__.value()).fold(),
            __.constant([])
            )
```

with:

```
by(coalesce(properties('p_v_tag').
   project('value').
     by(__.value()).
   fold(), 
   constant([]))
```

Comment: Thank you @stephen-mallette, your answer works. I'm working with janus-graph of version 0.2.0, recently I upgraded it to version 0.3.1, the method I used past works now. So this seems a problem related with version. With version 0.3.1, both `choose` and `coalesce` steps work.